# Did the new nodes accept the old blocks in hard fork?

Tags: blockchain-fork

i had knew that the old nodes will reject the new blocks.how about the new nodes treating the old blocks?
i got the definition of the hard fork in the [Hard Fork](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hard-fork.asp).but it didn't explain how did the new nodes treat the old blocks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the exact rule changes.

Comment: so it is uncertainly?

Comment: It is very certain, but it depends on the new rules. You could have a hardforking change in which the answer is yes, or one where the answer is no.

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer, you should specify which cryptocurrency, and which proposed or deployed hard forking change you're referring it.

Comment: i am sorry. i means bitcoin.i searched about the bitcoin would hard fork because the segwit and BU.would this hard fork made the old blocks(or old bitcoins in my wallet) lose value?